# functions to find average and peak value in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

my assignment:

program should feature 2 functions, one to calculate the average of the values in the array (returning result as double) and one to find peak value in array (returning result as unsigned value).  The array (unsigned ints) and number of values in the array(unsigned int) should be passed through functions as parameters.

Can someone please explain how to fix my code??

```
   #include <iostream>

   using namespace std;

   #define SIZE 10

   double findAverage (unsigned int);

   unsigned findPeak (unsigned int);

   unsigned numbers [SIZE] = {47, 1, 0, 1324, 99, 1000, 65536, 19, 0, 24000 };
   unsigned sum;
   unsigned peak;

    int main()
    {
        double average;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            sum += numbers[i];
        }

        average = findAverage(numbers[SIZE]);

        cout << "The average value is : " << average << endl;

        peak = findPeak(numbers[SIZE]);

        cout << "The peak value is : " << peak << endl;
    }
    double findAverage (unsigned sum)
    {
        double average;
        average = sum / SIZE;
        return average;
    }
    unsigned findPeak (unsigned int *)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < SIZE; i++)
        {

            if (numbers[i] > peak)
            {
                peak = numbers[i];
            }
        }
    return peak;
    }
```

Comment: _"Can someone please explain how to fix my code??"_ If you tell us, what exactly needs to be fixed with it (compiler errors, linker errors, runtime errors, unexpected output), may be.

Comment: `sum / SIZE` google integer math.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here a running version:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double findAverage (unsigned int *, unsigned int);

unsigned int findPeak (unsigned int *, unsigned int);

int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    unsigned int numbers [] = {47, 1, 0, 1324, 99, 1000, 65536, 19, 0, 24000 };

    double average = findAverage(numbers, size);

    cout << "The average value is : " << average << endl;

    unsigned int peak = findPeak(numbers, size);

    cout << "The peak value is : " << peak << endl;
}
double findAverage (unsigned int *numbers, unsigned int size)
{
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
    {
        sum += numbers[i];
    }
    double average = (double)sum / size;
    return average;
}
unsigned int findPeak (unsigned int *numbers, unsigned int size)
{
    unsigned int peak = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
    {

        if (numbers[i] > peak)
        {
            peak = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return peak;
}
```

Remarks:
You should avoid global variables.
I think the sum calculation makes more sense in `findAverage()`. Then it has to get passed the array.
The declaration of `findPeak` missed a `*`, it did not match the definition.
To pass an array, you must not provide any `[...]`. Just pass the pointer to the first element by writing the array name.
`average = sum / SIZE;` firstly evaluates `sum / SIZE` by doing an integer division, so the result is truncated. You have to cast one of the operands to force a double division.

Comment: I'm going to nitpick here and say sum and peak should be initialized to 0.  Average can be declared and defined on the same line.

Writing just "unsigned" is bad practice, and only works here because the compiler is assuming int as the type.

Also, he didn't follow the pattern but he said his functions should take in the size of the array, which they don't.

Comment: @dwcanillas you're right, Amadeusz made an edit for the initilization and i edited the other suggestion now

Answer (score 3):

From the assignment description:

> The array (unsigned ints) and number of values in the array(unsigned
>   int) should be passed through functions as parameters.

And where are there the two parameters in the functions?

```
   double findAverage (unsigned int);
   unsigned findPeak (unsigned int);
```

The functions can be defined the following way

```
   double findAverage( const unsigned int a[], unsigned int n )
   {
      double sum = 0.0;

      for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) sum += a[i];

      return n == 0 ? sum : sum / n;
   }

   unsigned int findPeak( const unsigned int a[], unsigned int n )
   {
      unsigned int max = 0;

      for ( unsigned int i = 1; i < n; i++ )
      {
         if ( a[max] < a[i] ) max = i;
      }

      return max;
   }
```

I defined function `findPeak` such a way that it retursn the index of the maximum element. You may rewrite it that it would return the maximum element itself.

Take into account that these tasks can be done with using standard algorithms `std::accumulate` and `std::max_element` declared respectively in headers `<numeric>` and 
`<algorithm>`.

Also there is no any need to define your varaibles in the global namepsace. They could be defined like local variables of main.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing numbers[SIZE] to findAverage instead of sum.

The parameter's name is missing in findPeak's definition.

Also, numbers[SIZE] is not in the array, numbers[SIZE-1] is the last element of the array, because indexing starts at 0.

It's also not a good idea to specify the size of the array and add the elements by hand (in {}). You can easily make a mistake.

Also, you should put all the code in the functions. So in main, you just call them. Don't use global variables either, they aren't necessary here at all and can cause all sorts of problems in bigger projects. So don't get used to bad habits. 
Just put your variables in main and pass them to the functions as parameters.
(You're actually doing this, but currently it's unnecessary because for example sum is global.)

Answer (score 0):

Your functions should be independent and reusable:

They should not rely on `SIZE`

They should not directly use the array: the array with the size should be parameters. Pass as `const` (no need to modify the array).

Below an example:

```
double findAverage (const unsigned myArray[], int arraySize)
{
    unsigned sum = 0;
    double average = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        sum += myArray[i];
    }

    if (arraySize) average = sum / arraySize;
    return average;
}

unsigned findPeak (const unsigned myArray[], int arraySize)
{
    unsigned peak = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        if (myArray[i] > peak)
        {
            peak = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return peak;
}
```

The call:

```
average = findAverage(numbers, SIZE);
peak = findPeak(numbers,SIZE);
```